# Double loop in Groovy

Tags: loops, groovy, each

How can I double loop using each if I have a structure like this:

```
Termin 1
[  [ 1][2 ][3 ]   ]
Termin 2
[  [1 ] [2 ] [3]  ]

Termin.each(){
            println("first");
           it.each(){
               println("second"); // 1 2 3 
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it` is used when you don't define the attribute name. You can just change the name:

```
def nested = [[1],[2],[3]]

nested.each { n ->
  n.each { s ->
    print "Nested: $s \n"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
`it` is implicit to the wrapped closure, so if you are fluent with Groovy semantics, you can also use

```
def nested = [[1],[2],[3]]

nested.each { 
  // `it` is meant for the nested.each{}
  it.each {
    // `it` is meant for the it.each{}
    print "Nested: $it \n"
  }
}
```

Both of the approach yield the same result.

Comment: You don't need to my dear friend. `it` is implicit to the wrapped closure.

Comment: @dmahapatro yes, but changing the name make your code more readable.

Comment: +1 Agree. It is for geeks like you. ;). Anyways, I have updated your answer, you can accept it if it is acceptable. :)

Comment: On SO, we're ALL geeks :-)  @dmahapatro

Comment: @Raffian Rightly said... :)